# Can't get past LightDM

Tags: boot, lightdm, ubuntu-mate

I don't know exactly what caused this, but I rebooted my Macbook Pro and when I tried to log back in to Ubuntu MATE, it took me back to the login screen. I have tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> on all of the keys <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>, and they all take me to black screens. <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> takes me back to LightDM.

I have also tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> on boot, and editing the GRUB boot option for Ubuntu. (I changed `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`). I pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot, but nothing changed. MATE would not start, nor would the other consoles show anything.

If I could just get into a command line then I could try to fix this (resetting .Xauthority, uninstalling nVidia's proprietary drivers, whatever I need to do), but I cannot even get to a command line! I really would not like to reinstall Linux right now, does anyone know how I can fix my problem and/or get to a command line?

Comment: Have you tried Recovery Mode? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: @arochester I somehow got to that menu at one point, I think when I was editing the "Advanced Boot Options for Ubuntu" entry and then booting by pressing F10, but I did not choose to go into recovery mode. Pressing Enter on that boot option just causes the computer to freeze up. I will try to get to that menu again and then get into recovery mode.

Comment: @arochester I've booted into recovery mode on both kernels available and the keyboard does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my login problem. It turns out that I had done a very Stupid Thing which was messing with the PATH variable without knowing what I was doing.

First, I booted the install media and chrooted to my ubuntu install (using the directions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure). I checked that .Xauthority had the correct permissions, and it did. So I uninstalled Nvidia's driver by running `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` in the chrooted environment and rebooted. This did nothing to help me log in, but (I think) it allowed me to change consoles. When I did change the console, it was showing a bunch of errors related to the PATH variable (such as "/usr/bin is not included in the PATH variable"). So I went into /etc/profile.d where I had created a shell script that edited the path variable. I saw the mistake I had made (literally a single space) and fixed it, and now everything is working.